# Entity, Entity Groups and List using Objectify 4

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm having some difficulty to solve this kind of problem:

I Have some nested entities and I'm trying to persist them in the same transaction (HRD enable).

Entity A:

```
@Entity 
public class A {
    @Id Long id;
    List<B> children;
}
```

Entity B:

```
@Entity 
public class B {
    @Id Long id;
}
```

When I try to persist 6 instances (just two Entity Groups, A e B) ...

```
public void testOfy() {
    ofy.getFactory().register(A.class);
    ofy.getFactory().register(B.class);

    List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();

    final A a0 = new A();
    final B b1 = new B();
    final B b2 = new B();
    final B b3 = new B();
    final B b4 = new B();
    final B b5 = new B();

    Ofy o = ofy.transaction();

    try {
        o.save().entities(b1).now(); list.add(b1);
        o.save().entities(b2).now(); list.add(b2);
        o.save().entities(b3).now(); list.add(b3);
        o.save().entities(b4).now(); list.add(b4);
        o.save().entities(b5).now(); list.add(b5);

        a0.children = list;
        o.save(a0);
        o.getTxn().commit();
    }

    finally {
        if (o.getTxn().isActive())
            o.getTxn().rollback();
    }

}
```

I get the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:36)
```

However if I put just 5 instances everything works...

```
public void testOfy() {
    ofy.getFactory().register(A.class);
    ofy.getFactory().register(B.class);

    List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();

    final A a0 = new A();
    final B b1 = new B();
    final B b2 = new B();
    final B b3 = new B();
    final B b4 = new B();
    final B b5 = new B();

    Ofy o = ofy.transaction();

    try {
        o.save().entities(b1).now(); list.add(b1);
        o.save().entities(b2).now(); list.add(b2);
        o.save().entities(b3).now(); list.add(b3);
        o.save().entities(b4).now(); list.add(b4);
        // o.save().entities(b5).now(); list.add(b5);

        a0.children = list;
        o.save(a0);
        o.getTxn().commit();
    }

    finally {
        if (o.getTxn().isActive())
            o.getTxn().rollback();
    }

}
```

I'm using Objectify 4.0b3, does anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood what an entity group is.  An entity group is not a *class*, it is an *instance* (or a group of instances).

Each of those entities represent a separate entity group.  XG transactions allow a maximum of five EGs per transaction.  The 6th produces the error you see.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! This greatly limits the use of transactions, I'll try an alternative way to persist the entities within the same transaction. Thank you again. :)